# Duplicating last tab by clicking + button with jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to create a tabbed page where the user can click a tab / button to duplicate the last tab as shown in the image below:

[image: Click plus to add tab]

In this case, you'd click the plus sign and `TAB 3` would be created with the same contents as `TAB 2`.

I'm  wondering what would be the best way to go about this?

Edit:

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/w3jysnr8/3) (be sure to hit run first) with the code I've so far.  It's almost there, but if your tab name has a space it doesn't dupe the last child html for some reason.

Comment: sharing the basic boilerplate code and css will greatly help those trying to help you.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of as far as I could get before my brain melted. It's almost there, but if your tab name has a space it doesn't dupe the last child html for some reason. (be sure to hit run first) http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/w3jysnr8/3/

Comment: Because `id` should be unique and it can't contain spaces... I've added an answer... BTW, you can use some caching if you move the `newTab` function to `.ready()` handler...

Comment: I've updated the answer to use some caching... You can find the old one where `newTab()` is outside `ready()` from revision history if necessary...

Comment: Last detail... I'm wondering how I would then make the newly created tab the active tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65544/discussion-between-kirk-ross-and-t-j).

Comment: Done! Would it be easy to also catch a return key press for the Create new tab button? i.e. clicking button || e.keyCode == 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to manually generate `id` rather than directly using the user input to generate `id`, since it should be unique, it can not contain spaces etc.

We can set the tab's title to user input while generating unique `id` behind the scene.

I've updated your code by making use of jquery [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs(),
    $dialog = $("#new_tab_dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 200,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create a new tab": function() {
          $dialog.dialog("close");
          var tid = parseInt($(".tab").last().attr("id").replace("tab", "")) + 1,
            li = $("<li/>").insertBefore("#list li:last");
          $("<a/>", {
            text: $("#new_tab_input").val(),
            href: "#tab" + tid
          }).appendTo(li);
          $("#tabs div.tab:last").clone().attr("id", "tab" + tid).appendTo("#tabs");
          $tabs.tabs("refresh").tabs("option", "active", -2);
          alert(tid);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $dialog.dialog("close");
        }
      },
      open: function() {
        $("#new_tab_input").val("");
      }
    });

  $("#create_tab").click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#new_tab_dialog" id="create_tab">+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    <p>Tab 1 content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
    <p>When you click the plus it should create a new tab (and corresponding div) by duplicating the last child in the list.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="new_tab_dialog" title="Duplicate the last tab">
  <input type="text" id="new_tab_input" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" placeholder="Enter new tab name" />
</div>
```

Side note: I've given a common class name for the content `<div>`'s to easily get the `id` like `$(".tab").last().attr("id")`, rather than getting it from the tabs which will look something like `$("#tabs").find("li:last").prev().find("a").attr("href")`

P.S: Looks like jquery ui keeps on attempting to fetch the content even if `#` is specified for the tab's anchor. I've given it the `id` of dialog instead to satisfy the poor thing.